# Most time efficient data structure for storing results of a two player game

Tags: data-structures

Given two players where one is the winner, and one is the loser, what would be the most efficient way to store this data given that I need to

- Check if a given player has beaten another given player
- List all of the players a given player has beaten
- List all of the players a given player has lost to
- List all of the players a given player has played with
- List all of the game results

I was considering using a Hash Map of key Player, and value a list of losers, but this doesn't seem efficient when listing all of the players a player has lost to, as the time complexity is n^2

Comment: Rather than a hash map of Player and a value list of losers, why not a hash map of player, and a value lis of {opponent,outcome}. That way you know who the player played, and the outcome of every match.

Answer (score 1):

While the `HashMap` with the key as a Player and value as either list of losers or `{ opponent, outcome }` would be the easiest solution to implement, I would say it is not the most space efficient solution.

For each user, you will have to maintain a `HashMap` and that map would have duplicate entries. For example, if a player `A` has played with `B` and won, `HashMap` for `A` would have an entry of `{ B, "WON" }` and player `B` will have an entry of `{ A, "LOST" }` which is not required since we can imply that if player `A` has won, player `B` must have lost.

I would suggest using a `Graph` data structure to tackle the problem. A graph `G = (V, E)` would have `V` as a set of users and `E` as a set of Edges between users with one more property of which player won.

Here is a visual representation to get the better idea:

[image: players as graph nodes]

With this implementation, you can avoid the duplication which will be there in case of `HashMap`

**The queries:**

**1.** Check if a given player `(X)` has beaten another given player `(Y)`
**>** Perform only one level of `DFS` from `X`. Check whether the current player is `Y`. If the player is `Y`, check edge value. If the edge value is `X`, `X` has won otherwise `Y` has won. If the `Y` is not in the edge list, player `X` has never played with `Y`
Time complexity: `O(E)` where `E` is the list of Edges incident on node `X`.

**2.** List all of the players a given player (X) has beaten
**>** Perform one level `DFS` from `X`. Check edge value. If the edge value is `X`, `X` has won and thus, add Node at the other end of Edge to the list.
Time complexity: `O(E)` where `E` is the list of Edges incident on node `X`.

**3.** List all of the players a given player (X) has lost to
**>** Same as 2.

**4.** List all of the players a given player has played with
**>** Same as 2.

**5.** List all of the game results
**>** Perform a complete DFS.
Time complexity: `O(E)` where `E` is the list of Edges.